# Process API for multiple children partial addition

Tags: c, pipe, parent-child

I have created a program that creates 3 children and sends a piece of the array to each child, then each child computes the summation of the array and prints it with the process ID then sends the summation to the parent which in turn will add the values and print the final sum. My question is when I go to run my code I get random child and parent outputs after the child partial summations and parent summation.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
  pid_t child_pid[3] ;
  //Define the array to hold the set of numbers
  int setNum[6] = {2,3,7,-1,10,6}, sum[3] = {0, 0, 0}, j;

  //Display the parents process ID
  printf("I am the parent with process ID: %d \n", (int) getppid());

  //Create a process
  for(j=0; j<3; j++)
  {
    child_pid[j] = fork();
  }
  j=0;
  if (child_pid[0] != 0)
  {
    //calculate the sum
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
      sum[j] = sum[j] + setNum[i];
    printf("I am the child with process ID: %d and I am sending %d to my parent\n", child_pid[0], sum[j]);
    j=j+1;
  }
  if (child_pid[1] != 0)
  {
    //calculate the sum
    for(int i=2; i<4; i++)
      sum[j] = sum[j] + setNum[i];
    printf("I am the child with process ID: %d and I am sending %d to my parent\n", child_pid[1], sum[j]);
    j=j+1;
  }
  if (child_pid[2] != 0)
  {
    //calculate the sum
    for(int i=4; i<6; i++)
      sum[j] = sum[j] + setNum[i];
    printf("I am the child with process ID: %d and I am sending %d to my parent\n", child_pid[2], sum[j]);
    j=j+1;
  }


  //Print the parent with final sum
  int final_sum = sum[0] + sum[1] +sum[2];

  printf("I am the parent with process ID: %d with a final sum of %d\n", (int) getppid(), final_sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems.

- Your initial fork() loop will result in 7 descendant processes being created, not the 3 you intend. If fork() returns 0, you're in a child process and shouldn't fork() further.
- Once a process fork()s, by default, it no longer shares any of its memory with its parent. You either need to set up the bits of memory you're using to stay shared (such as with mmap with `MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS`), or pass the results back via a pipe or socket or something.
- Your tests of child_pid elements against 0 are backwards. You're running the child logic in every process except the right one.
- Your child processes are all printing the end text that only the parent process is supposed to print.
- You're using getppid(), which gets the parent PID, but your code indicates that you're trying to get the process's own PID, which is done by getpid().